# Send task to background in an "if"

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

Why is this?

```
if true; then sleep 3 &; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I want to run

```
sleep 3
```

in the background so that the command ["sleep 3" is just an example] would run in "paralell" style, so it finishes faster. But I'm getting this:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

error message. Why? Why can't I send a task to the background?

Comment: What do you think you're testing with the `if` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you don't need to separate commands in that case (`&` separated them itself).

For example.

```
$> if true; then (sleep 3; echo ok) &  fi
[1] 14224
$> ok
```

Comment: This works but spawns a subshell, i.e. an extra process (which extra memory burden, and variable settings you do inside the `( ... )` will not be visible outside)

Answer (score 14):

It is because `&` is already a statement separator, so you should not put `;` after this.

Comment: This should be more like the accepted answer than the one from 2011-10-12, 11:34 by @ДМИТРИЙ-МАЛИКОВ.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it multiline:

```
if true; then
  sleep 3 &
fi
```